# Unintended skewing of independent factors (?): How bad did I mess up when collecting data and can I fix it?

Tags: regression, anova, autocorrelation, multicollinearity

Up front: I can give more details if needed, but I think my question is pretty basic: did I accidentally skew my independent variables so bad that I can't use them?

I did a study where I dove along a river collecting mussels. Before we even look at the mussels in the study, I want to make sure I'm using the independent factors correctly. I recorded the depth I dove, and also what type of bottom there was (rock, sand...all standardized into a continuous scale). All of this was done to see if depth, bottom type, and river mile (distance along the river) had any impact on mussels.

What I found is that I unintentionally dove deeper at downstream sites than upstream. This is strange as I did not move in one direction (I dove upstream some weeks, bounced downstream, back to the middle...it was based on logistics). The regression shows an R2 of 0.106, and the analysis of variance shows a significant p value.

So my question is: am I unable to analyze the dependent mussel data (size, weight, %adults, etc) with depth and river mile as separate independent variables?

P.S. An ANOVA examining the effects of depth and river mile on bottom type resulted in a significant interaction...

Comment: is depth of the river not correlated with distance downstream? Or did you record depth of dive as proportion of depth at the location of the dive?

Comment: My hope was that I could keep depth relatively constant over the length of the river. I recorded depth as the initial reading when we hit the bottom of the river. The sites further downstream were unintentionally deeper, and the correlation R2 was 0.106

Also: I realize that many rivers get deeper and deeper as the river continues downstream, but we stayed out of the shipping lane and in relatively shallow waters (4-11 meters).